# Why I get no overload matches with typeorm and nest.js

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nest

Hey I'm trying to create an entity for task and use this entity,

so here is my task entity:

```
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Status } from './Status.entity';
import { User } from './User.entity';

@Entity()
export class Task {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    type: 'bigint',
    name: 'task_id',
  })
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Status)
  @JoinColumn()
  status: Status;

  @OneToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn()
  createdBy: User;

  @OneToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn()
  updatedBy: User;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
    name: 'created_at',
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
    name: 'updated_at',
  })
  updateAt: Date;
}
```

and I have everything else in the project already like the Status entity, and the user entity

when I'm trying to create a task like this

```
 async insertTask(title: string, description: string, userId: number) {
    const userDetails = await this.findUser(userId)
    const newTask = this.TaskRepository.create({
      title,
      description,
      createdBy: userDetails,
    });

    const res = await this.TaskRepository.save(newTask)

    return res;
  }
```

I get this error:

```
(node:5772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: Duplicate entry '8' for key 'task.REL_91d76dd2ae372b9b7dfb6bf3fd'
    at Query.onResult (C:\Users\Kryolos.Hakeem\desktop\vodafone-tech-test\back-end\vodafone-test\src\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts:222:33)
    at Query.execute (C:\Users\Kryolos.Hakeem\desktop\vodafone-tech-test\back-end\vodafone-test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:36:14)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (C:\Users\Kryolos.Hakeem\desktop\vodafone-tech-test\back-end\vodafone-test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)       
    at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\Kryolos.Hakeem\desktop\vodafone-tech-test\back-end\vodafone-test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\Kryolos.Hakeem\desktop\vodafone-tech-test\back-end\vodafone-test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)       
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kryolos.Hakeem\desktop\vodafone-tech-test\back-end\vodafone-test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5772) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:5772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NotFoundException: User Not Found
    at TasksService.findUser (C:\Users\Kryolos.Hakeem\desktop\vodafone-tech-test\back-end\vodafone-test\src\tasks\tasks.service.ts:70:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at TasksService.insertTask (C:\Users\Kryolos.Hakeem\desktop\vodafone-tech-test\back-end\vodafone-test\src\tasks\tasks.service.ts:19:25)
(node:5772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

I have been stuck with this for a long time now, any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

this is because `updatedBy` and `createdBy` fields on `Task` has the type `User` but you're supplying a `number` (the `userId` parameter).

Comment: try this: `this.TaskRepository.create({ description, status: 1 })`. are you getting any error now?

Comment: man, I need the title value

Comment: I meant, `this.TaskRepository.create({ description, title })`

Comment: no, the issue wasn't here, I fixed it,

Comment: the issue was in the type of userDetails, it was a promise I had to put an await their first, it solved it, now I'm facing another issue

Comment: I'm gonna update the question

Comment: you're missing some `await` somewhere in the code, then a rejected promise will trigger that warning.

Comment: probably when calling `insertTask`.